# How to add libxml2.dylib in xcode 7

Tags: ios, xml, xmpp, libxml2, xmppframework

I am trying to add xmpp framework in my ios app.After adding it's showing

> libxml/tree.h file not found

after some googling I found that need to add libxml2.dylib  in Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries.But I am not finding this file. but i found .tbd file.I try to add .tbd file and set Header search path as `$(SDKROOT)/usr/include/libxml2` but it still showing same error.

I know that same question asked many times but I am not solving this issue.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add libxml2.dylib follow these steps

- Go to general tab and click on + button in Link Frameworks and Libraries
- Click on Add Other button then
- press cmd+Shift+G and write below path and add it

> /usr/lib/libxml2.dylib

Answer (score 3):

set your Link Frameworks Automatically to YES in Build Settings,
then go to general tab and in click on + button in Link Frameworks and Libraries there search for libxml2.tbd and add

Comment: I tried this but it's not working,after implement your steps now I am getting following three errors:Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_dns_free_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
  "_dns_parse_resource_record", referenced from:
      -[XMPPSRVResolver processRecord:length:] in XMPPSRVResolver.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: sorry for bad English. I used OpenSSL library in my project and I faced similar issue. Make sure that the xmpp framwork is compiled for  architecture x86_64. I think it is related to your problem. Hope it helps

Comment: the SHELL file for build ".sh" file should contain string like this one for Architectures  (  ARCHS="i386 x86_64 armv7 armv7s arm64 tv_x86_64 tv_arm64"   )

Comment: after some modification and Now I am getting only one error "ld: 13 duplicate symbols for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: check your Project -> Project Target -> Build Settings -> Other Linker Flags. 
Check if you have added -ObjC in Other Linker Flags.
if you it is present there select it and click on - button at bottom and then clean and retry..
Hope it works. :)